# Creating List of String elements that occur a certain amount of times using only the List ADT

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

I am tasked with creating a list with no duplicates of all String elements, in this case first names, of an `ArrayList`. The method is passed a threshold, and the method must store the first name if it has occurred at least the amount of the threshold. The restriction is that I am only allowed to use the `List` ADT. I have this code storing it in a `ArrayList` and it works, but I am worried about the algorithmic complexity which seems to be \$O(n^2)\$ as a worst case. Is there a more efficient way of writing this method?

```
static List<String> commonFirstNames(ArrayList<Student> students, int threshold) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] nameArray;
    String firstName;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        nameArray = students.get(i).getName().split(" ");
        firstName = nameArray[0];

        boolean isInResults = results.contains(firstName);
        if (!isInResults) {
            for (int j = i; j < students.size(); j++) {
                String[] otherNameArray = students.get(j).getName().split(" ");
                String otherFirstName = otherNameArray[0];

                if (otherFirstName.equals(firstName)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter >= threshold) {
                results.add(firstName);
            }
        }
            counter = 0; 
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can "easily" merge-sort lists, an add a walk to weed out names not occurring often enough.

Comment: What do you mean by ad a walk?

Comment: Walk the sorted list: sorting should cluster like key values/identical names. From a start index _i_, check threshold _t_ - 1 entries further down: if identical, you have a name to store, and the next start index is the index of the first name (further down) that differs. If not identical, the name at _i+t-1_ is the next candidate: find its first occurrence as the next start index (_If_ speed _was_ an issue, you could use galloping search for both). Or just keep counting while the name doesn't change - time usage should be dominated by sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a hint but unfortunately I cannot comment on your post.

As greybeard already mentioned, you could sort the List and then count the elements with equal `firstName`. A representation of the sorted List may give you an idea how to implement this:

```
List("Alice A", "Alice B", "Alice C", "Brian A", "Brian B", "Jason A", "Jason B", "Jason C", ...)
```

Another solution is to use a Collection that counts equal entries.

This Collection implementation is often available as Bag. This is unfortunately not included in the Java standard library, but implementations are available in [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html). Note that you have to transform the List of `firstName` + `lastName` to a list that only contains the `firstName`. You can use a [Transformer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Transformer.html) also available in Apache Commons that strips the `lastName` (the values of the resulting List will then be lazy evaluated).